# How to Incorporate ISA & GS Segment Values into EDI XML generated by BizTalk 2009

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

I have a receive port setup in BizTalk 2009 to accept & disassemble X12837 EDI Files. There is also a send port that picks up disassembled EDI from the receive port and converts into EDI XML files. The send port is associated with a Party, with the ISA & GS segment values associated with it.

My Issue is that BizTalk pulls out ISA & GS segments out of the disassembled EDI XML files.

How can I get BizTalk to populate the ISA & GS segments into the disassembled EDI XML generated?

Answer (score 0):

BizTalk pulls out the ISA and GS segments and promotes some of the data to the message context provided you have a party configured with the appropriate ISA/GS data. You can subscribe send ports and orchestrations to the promoted data for message routing or you can reference the data within an orchestration expression shape if you need it for some other purpose.

Please clarify your requirements and I will be sure to respond with more specific details.